# streaming json back from spring

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, extjs, jackson

The spring controller return a json output to populate the extJs combobox.
I am using spring 3.0.2 and the jackson 2.2.3 libraries are included.

The controller class:

```
@RequestMapping(value="getStates.json", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody Map<String,? extends Object> loadStates() {

        HashMap<String, List<State>> modelMap = new HashMap<String,List<State>>();
        modelMap.put("states", stateService.getBrazilianStates());
        System.out.println("Returning : " + modelMap.size());
        return modelMap;
    }
```

ExtJs:

```
Ext.onReady(function(){

    var store = new Ext.data.Store({
        proxy: new Ext.data.HttpProxy({
            url: 'getStates.json'
        }),
        reader: new Ext.data.JsonReader({
            root:'states'
        },
        [{name: 'code'},
         {name: 'name'}
        ])
    });

    var combo = new Ext.form.ComboBox({
        id: 'statesCombo',
        store: store,
        displayField: 'name',
        valueField: 'code',
        hiddenName : 'codeId',
        typeAhead: true,
        mode: 'local',
        fieldLabel: 'States of Brazil',
        anchor: '100%',
        forceSelection: true,
        triggerAction: 'all',
        emptyText:'Select a state...',
        selectOnFocus:true
    });
```

The combo-box drop-down however is empty.
What am i doing wrong?
I expected not to be needign any explicit mapping with teh @responsebody annotation.

Comment: Are you sure your modelMap gets populated in the controller?

Comment: yes - it does.I am not sure how to print out the responsebody though.

Comment: Use curl to simulate the call you "think" is happening, or use Chrome's Developer Tools or Firefox's Firebug to see the request/response pairs of your running application.  Odds are, either the request is not going where you thought it was, the response is not containing what you thought it did, or something is messed up in your JS and it's not handling the request right.

Comment: Since I have not got  any meaningful sample around responsebody - needed to confirm if I need to put in any configuration in the servlet xml for the jackson converters.

Answer (score 0):

I had missed out adding the jackson converter to the messageconverters.